# .Net Core, merge two lists, remove invalid entries and keep values in the original list

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

I have a default list of attributes and in incoming list of attributes. I need to remove any items from the incoming list that do now match the **Name** in the default list. I have tried many different LINQ queries, but have not been able to accomplish this task.

Default List:

```
Attributes[] defaultAttributes = 
{
    new ProfileAttributes() { Name = "FirstName", Include = false, Required = false },
    new ProfileAttributes() { Name = "MiddleName", Include = false, Required = false },
    new ProfileAttributes() { Name = "HomeCountry", Include = false, Required = false },
...
```

I want to merge the two lists and remove any items where the **`Name`** of the incoming list does not match the default list.

For example in the following remove Favorite color because it is an invalid name and preserve the required values.

```
Attributes[] incomingAttributes = 
{
    new ProfileAttributes() { Name = "FavoriteColor", Required = true },
    new ProfileAttributes() { Name = "MiddleName", Required = false},
    new ProfileAttributes() { Name = "HomeCountry", Required = true },
```

Most incoming lists will not have "Include" So I need to add that and set it to true if it is in the incoming list, otherwise false. I have done that with the following, but interested if there is a way to combine this with the merge.

**Revised, I used the following solution:**
I used lists instead of array lists. I found this easier to loop through and bind to checkboxes on the form

```
Attributes[] defaultAttributes
```

to

```
List<ProfileAttributes> defaultAttributes = new List<ProfileAttributes>()
```

Inside the loop for my form:

```
<input type="checkbox"for="myModel.ProfileAttributes[i].Include"
```

I created an empty list:

```
 List<ProfileAttributes> validListAttributes = new();
```

Then I created a loop. If the name is valid add it to the empty list and add the Include attribute:

```
 foreach (var a in myModel.ProfileAttributes) //incomingAttributes
 {
    if (defaultAttributes.Any(d => d.Name == a.Name))
    {
        a.Include = true;
        validListAttributes.Add(a);
    }
 }
```

Then another loop to add missing attributes because all attributes must be display on the form:

```
foreach (var d in defaultAttributes)
{
   if (!validListAttributes.Any(v => v.Name == d.Name))
   {
      validListAttributes.Add(d);
    }
}
```

Then update the model with the valid list containing all attributes:

```
myModel.ProfileAttributes = validListAttributes.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be a lot easier with a generic IEqualityComparer whose job is to compare the Name property of the instances involved in the process.

So let's define an IEqualityComparer for the Attributes class

```
public class ProfileAttributesComparer : IEqualityComparer<ProfileAttributes>
{
    public bool Equals(ProfileAttributes obj1, ProfileAttributes obj2)
    {
        if(obj1 == null && obj2 == null)
            return true;
        if(obj1 == null || obj2 == null)
            return false;
            
        var result = string.Compare(obj1.Name, obj2.Name,  
                         StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
        return result == 0;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(ProfileAttributes obj)
    {
        return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now you can process the elements in the *incomingAttributes* that have a name equal to an instance inside the *defaultAttributes*  and change the property Include to true

```
var result = incomingAttributes
    .Where(x => defaultAttributes.Contains(x, new ProfileAttributesComparer()))
    .Select(p => { p.Include = true; return p;});
```

The *result* variable contains only the items with the same name but the *incomingAttributes* list still has three items and two of them have the Include property changed to true.